# Semantic-UI Dependency Stuck on Ongoing Build on Azure Devops Pipelines

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, semantic-ui

I have a node app and I am trying to build it on azure pipeline, but the build gets stuck at the selection where you have to choose between automatic or custom. Is there a way to skip this so it build perfectly?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EAhX.png)

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the answer helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [document](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html#install-semantic-ui), we can know: The first time you run gulp you will be greeted with an **interactive** installer, as far as I know, the pipeline cannot handle such interactive setup.

> The easiest way to install Semantic UI is our NPM package which
> contains special install scripts to make setup **interactive** and
> updates seamless.

The install process will create two files: `semantic.json` stores paths for your build and sits on the top-level of your project, `theme.config` is a LESS file that exists in `src/` and allows you to centrally set the themes for each UI component.

The installer will also create a special folder which contains your site-specific themes. The default location for this is `src/site`. For details, please refer to this [document](http://learnsemantic.com/guide/expert.html).

So a workaround I can think of is that you can run the `npm install semantic-ui --save` command locally, and then publish the generated files from the local to the azure repo.